# About “dark l” sound in daily conversation

Tags: pronunciation, conversation, phonetics

Could you please tell me that if you really make the dark l sound in words like “call” “wall” “fall” or “hole” in daily conversation, like you can feel the movement of your tongue, or just do it when speaking slowly or very clearly? I can’t really tell the difference when I myself is speaking.

Comment: I feel it, even when speaking normally.

Comment: I can't feel or hear the difference, even after reading a number of explanations over the years.